# Tooltip on disabled Tab - Material Ui, React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I am new to React and UI in general.

can someone help me to correct this?

I am using Material Ui Tabs in my Component and not able to get a tooltip on one of the disabled Tab.(code snippet added below)

```
<Tooltip title={sample_title}>
       <span>
          <Tab
          disabled
          value={some_Random_title}
          classes={tabStyleOne}
          label={
          (
           <Typography variant="caption" align="center" classes={renditionHeader}>
           {some_random-text}
           </Typography>
          )
          }
         />
     </span>
</Tooltip>
```

I am encapsulating my Tab in Span as asked in Material-UI Tabs Documentation for disabled Tabs

https://codesandbox.io/s/wc74r?file=/demo.js

Please help me understand where I am doing wrong. and how to achieve tooltip on disabled Tab in material UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

this is what I found I while ago and what I'm currently using.

```
// outside the component
function CloneProps(props) {
  const { children, ...other } = props;
  return children(other);
}

// when you render the component
<Tabs value={selectedTab} textColor="inherit" indicatorColor="secondary">
  <Tab 
    component={NavLink} 
    to={`${url}/tab1`} 
    label="Tab 1" 
  />
  {/* Hack for tooltip on disabled tab */}
  <CloneProps>  
    { tabProps => (
      <Tooltip title={tabIsDisabled ? "Tooltip title" : ""} arrow>
        <div>
          <Tab 
            {...tabProps}
            component={NavLink} 
            to={`${url}/tab2`}
            label="Tab 2" 
            disabled={tabIsDisabled}
          />
        </div>
      </Tooltip>
    )}
  </CloneProps>
</Tabs>
```

Mauro

Comment: Great solution ! tested with mui v4